# SharePoint Online Modern Site-Show link on display form in ready only mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

I have a link in a multiline column/hyperlink column. I want to show this column only on display form and strictly not on Edit/new form in modern sharepoint site. ShowInEditForm=false not working on Modern Site as form is shared in Edit and Display mode.

I wanted to show link as anchor tag only. Does anybody know workaround for it.

I tried calculated column - it doesnt show link. it shows plain text.
I tried column formating- column formating is working only on view not on Display form

Please suggest

Comment: Are you using plain or rich text multiple lines of text column? How you will enter link in text column if it is hidden on new form? Will the hyperlink fixed for all list items?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the box feature to set permission restriction on editing column in SharePoint Online.
However, some third-party tools or java scripts may achieve this feature. Here is a thread for your reference:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-online-office-365-column-level-security-iss/